# Как добавить данные в meta-data заказа?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Магазин на WordPress с WooCommerce.

На сайте продаются услуги - сдается помещение в аренду. Посетители выбирают дату и время, оплачивают и получают код доступа к помещению (генерится на сайте через API замка). Встает вопрос - как сохранить в базе сгенеренный код доступа, чтобы он был привязан к заказу и мы могли его выводить в личном кабинете?

Сейчас в заказ в мета-данные (meta data) записывается время и дата визита. Это делается через готовый плагин (в принципе, все бронирование ведется через плагин). Я ищу способы дозаписать также в заказ код доступа, но не понимаю как это сделать, потому что плохо понимаю архитектуру WordPress и общую логику некоторых процессов.

После того, как заказ оплачен, я запускаю вот такой код. В нем я вывожу данные по бронированию и хочу добавить к заказу новые данные (код доступа к помещению).

```
// Получаем все "товары" из заказа    
$order_items = $order->get_items();

    // Для каждого "товара" из заказа...
    foreach ($order_items as $item_id => $item ){ 

        // ... просматриваем все мета-данные
        foreach ( $item->get_formatted_meta_data() as $meta_id => $meta ) {

            // Выводим значения мета-данных
            echo $meta->display_value; 

        }

        // Этот код не работает. 
        wc_update_order_item_meta ( $item_id, 'passcode', "мой пароль", '');
        update_post_meta ($item_id, 'passcode', "мой пароль", '');
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: `update_post_meta ($order->id(), 'passcode', "мой пароль", '');` Надеюсь так будет понятно где у вас ошибка =) p.s. я не уверен что у вас есть переменная $order =) но вам нужен ID заказа, а не элемента(услуги\товара) заказа =)

Comment: Владимир, спасибо. Но у меня другая задача. Если в заказе три услуги (товара), то мне для каждой надо прописать индивидуальную meta-data. В этом случае, если я буду указывть order->id, я получается пропишу их для всего заказа, а не для каждого товара. Может мне как-то другим способом можно записывать информацию для каждого товара в заказе?